# Creating graphics/visualisations from C++ (Qt) and passing them to R

Tags: c++, r, qt, visualization, rcpp

I have a C++/Qt library that is producing some specialised visualisations; the visualisations are currently produced using Qt's QPainter system and primitives.
I would like to extend my library to produce these visualisations for R.

I already have a bridge between my C++ library and R using Rcpp, that works for exchanging basic data structures e.g. exposing data from the library as data-frames etc.
However I am a bit lost on what the next step should be in order to output R graphics from C++.

If it is possible to use the Qt infrastructure, it would be great as it would improve code reuse. However, if it is not at all possible, I would be willing to rewrite the visualisation code using the primitives of another system. Note that Qt can output SVG.

Do you have any advice on how to use Rcpp (or something else) to achieve this goal. Could you perhaps point me to other C++ libraries that produce visualisations for R? (Note: this does not include graphics libraries written in R for R).

Comment: I don't understand the question.  To make it more specific:  are you aiming to _make a `svg` plot in C++ using Qt_ and then using R to plot it?  Or the inverse?   Do you want a standalone C++ executable -- if so, then RInside already _has Qt examples_.  And, of course, welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: Thank you for your very fast reply!
The desired result would be to be able to write in R:

`library(mylib)`
`a <- mylibdataread("blah blah")`
`mylibplot(a, "partid", 4, 6)`
(and the visualisation appears in R)

where mylib is an R package that uses Rcpp to expose functions (mylibread and mylibplot) from a C++/Qt library into R. The functions mylibread and mylibplot would be written in C++.
I'm not sure passing through SVG is the best option; I just mentioned it as a possibility.

Comment: The RInside example solves the problem in the inverse direction: plot in R -> svg -> C++ stand-alone executable. I am seeking a way to do C++ library -> R package -> (some format) -> plot in R.

Comment: So you want an R function to do what you do now in Qt?  That is not trivial as plotting is simply different between both systems.  For starters, I am not aware of a single Rcpp-using package _implementing a plot function_.  Maybe rethink the approach in having your package compute _data_ which you then _plot in R_.

Comment: Thanks! Although I use the verb "plot", the visualisation is not the typical charts one has in R (histograms, lines, bars, scatterplots and the like). Very useful to know, though, that not a single Rcpp-based package creates graphics in C++ and sends them to R. I may have to look into libraries like plotly to see how and to what extent they achieve code reuse.

Comment: There once was an effort around packages `qtutils`, `qtbase` and `qtpaint` but that seems to have died as doing this portably across OSs is very hard.  See https://github.com/ggobi/ for the repos.

Comment: Correction: qtpaint is still at CRAN -- https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/qtpaint/index.html